# OSGi like module life cycle for Angular (2/4)

Tags: javascript, java, angular, osgi, frontend

As you may already familiar with OSGi, it's structure and module life cycle. I am wondering if we can have the concept and structure for Angular.

My scenario is that I want to develop a modular application. I want to use OSGi for handling business logic so everyone can develop their own module and install it in the OSGi environment as a 3th party functionality. For the front-end i need the same thing for Angular.

So the question is do we have OSGi like module structure and life cycle for Angular? If not then do you have any other front-end js library in mind that meets my scenario ?

Thanks

Comment: I am developing a framework that is heading that direction, although not using Angular: https://github.com/erdalkaraca/hi5